# Simplify foreach array builder with isset tests for keys

Tags: php, arrays

For the following dataset (`$data`), I'm building a multidimensional array. For each unique key (`a`) there will be an array of `b` values associated with it.

```
$data = [
  ['a' => 1, 'b' => 23],
  ['a' => 1, 'b' => 97],
  ['a' => 2, 'b' => 23],
  ['a' => 1, 'b' => 47],
  ['a' => 3, 'b' => 23],
];

$result = [];
foreach ($data as $d) {
  if (!isset($result[$d['a']]))
    $result[$d['a']] = [];
  $result[$d['a']][] = $d['b'];
}

print_r($result);

/*
Output should be:

[ 
  1 => [23, 97, 47],
  2 => [23],
  3 => [23],
]
*/
```

The `if (!isset($result[$d['a']])) $result[$d['a']] = [];` part is ugly. Is there a sexier/more-efficient way to build this desired output?

**Update:**
Thanks everyone, looks like I could just go (without even initializing `$result = [];`)

```
foreach ($data as $d)
  $result[$d['a']][] = $d['b'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That check is not needed at all. If it is not a array, it will created when the first item is added.

So the "sexier" solution is to remove the if and initialization...

Comment: doesn't this throw a notice?

Comment: Didn't for me. But that might be due to PHP configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Dont have to use the isset() function.

try this code to make it "sexier".

`$data = [`

```
  ['a' => 1, 'b' => 23],
  ['a' => 1, 'b' => 97],
  ['a' => 2, 'b' => 23],
  ['a' => 1, 'b' => 47],
  ['a' => 3, 'b' => 23],
];

$result = [];
foreach ($data as $d) {
    $result[$d['a']][]= $d['b'];
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Isn't that what I said 12min ago?

Comment: I agree to to that...i just provided the code.. sorry if that bothers you.. note: this was actually @fredrik said.